# knockout.js with kendo UI MultiSelect over MVC 5

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5

Currently I have the following code, MVC with knockout bindings (this works fine)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.profiles,
    (SelectList)Model.profileItems, new
        {
            id = "ID",
            data_bind = "options: Profiles_msl, optionsText: 'profiles', optionsValue: 'ID'"
        })
```

I also have this which is kendo UI with MVC model bindings (no knockout). This also works.

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
    .Name("Profiles")
    .BindTo(new SelectList(ViewBag.Profiles_msl, "ID", "profiles"))
    .Value(new[] { new { } })
)
```

The main question is: how can I bind my knockout to the kendo UI similar to how I have done with the standard mvc?

If you need more code: let me know. The list is just an `IQueryable` array from the controller in mvc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HtmlAttributes is the key

```
 @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
.Name("Profiles")
.BindTo(new SelectList(ViewBag.Profiles_msl, "ID", "profiles"))
.Value(new[] { new { } })
.HtmlAttributes(new{id="ID",
             data_bind = 
"options: Profiles_msl, optionsText: 'profiles', optionsValue: 'ID'"
  });
 )
```

Comment: This passes the attributes but you lose all the styling from kendo

Comment: actually got it working no was an old example I had not working thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to use BindTo if your passing the data array over knockout you dont need this, same as @Bellash answer just remove the BindTo, itll still work fine.

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
.Name("Profiles")
.Value(new[] { new { } })
.HtmlAttributes(new{id="ID",
             data_bind = 
"options: Profiles_msl, optionsText: 'profiles', optionsValue: 'ID'"
  });
 )
```

Thanks A